# How to drop a collection whose name contains "_"?

Tags: mongodb

I create a collection in Mongodb with a name like "*col", and it seems like with name contains character "*", you cannot use db.COLLECTION_NAME.drop() to drop it??

[image]

the "_jihui" collection is what I'm referring to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [getCollection()](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.getCollection/) method for that purpose:

```
db.getCollection('_col').drop()
```

Answer (score 0):

you can enclose your collection name in square brackets when the collection contain some kind of special characters in its name.

eg : `db["my-db--collection"].drop()`

Comment: I called db["_col"].drop(), does not work, "_col" shows up when I call show collections...

Comment: and... ? whats the result

Comment: how did you create  that collection ? because when i try to create a collection like db._col.insert(), mongodb does not allow me to do so. i can create db.a_col.insert() though